# How to make a loop in Python that asks for the user to type this or that and they get a different response for both, and if it's invalid it loops?

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, while-loop, nested-loops

New to Python. Working on a program and I want to add a loop so that if they don't put in 1 or 2 then they are asked to try again until they do it right. In my assignment, I'm making a cafe. I want to ask the user if they are dining in or ordering take out (1 or 2) and each option offers a different response. 1 for example would output "Thank you for dining in with us" and 2 would output: "Thank you for choosing take out". If they put anything other than 1 or 2, I want it to prompt them to try again until they put the right response in. This would be a loop right?

This is what I have so far and the loop part I have is a complete mess and doesn't run at all.

```
print("Will you be dining in or ordering take out?")
while True:
    try:
        where = input("For Dine In, Type 1. For Take Out, Type 2: ")
        if where == "1":
            print("Thank you for dining in with us. Please fill out the following: ")
        elif where == "2":
            print("Thank you for choosing take out. Please fill out the following: ")
        else:
            print("Invalid response, please type 1 or 2: ")  
        except
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Remove `except`

Comment: @DMalan the "try" is still showing as an error when I delete except. Should I delete that? Also, it doesn't loop when you put the incorrect input in like I want it to.

Comment: What error does it show?

Comment: move the except out one indentation level and pass the keyword pass indented under it.

Comment: If you do want to use `except`, format it correctly by adding a colon after it an a line below that will handle the except.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In your own words, where the code says `try` and `except`, **what is the intended purpose** of these lines? What do you think they are for, and how do you think they work?

Comment: "I want it to prompt them to try again until they put the right response in. This would be a loop right?" Yes. Next step to think about: **What should happen** when the response is valid? Then the code should **stop** looping, right? What tools do you know about for this purpose?

Comment: Note that the author mentioned this was the start of what he was doing,  there may be more code to come where the try/except would be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error in your code is that `except` is supposed to have a block after it -- but you do not need `try/except` at all since nothing you're doing is expected to raise an exception.  Just `break` the loop once you have a valid response.

```
print("Will you be dining in or ordering take out?")
while True:
    where = input("For Dine In, Type 1. For Take Out, Type 2: ")
    if where == "1":
        print("Thank you for dining in with us. Please fill out the following: ")
        break
    elif where == "2":
        print("Thank you for choosing take out. Please fill out the following: ")
        break
    else:
        print("Invalid response, please type 1 or 2: ")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
print("Will you be dining in or ordering take out?")
while True:
    try:
        where = input("For Dine In, Type 1. For Take Out, Type 2: ")
        if where == "1":
            print("Thank you for dining in with us. Please fill out the following: ")
        elif where == "2":
            print("Thank you for choosing take out. Please fill out the following: ")
        else:
            print("Invalid response, please type 1 or 2: ")  
    except:
        pass
```